# Yarn report flink job as FINISHED and SUCCEED when flink job failure

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I am running flink job on yarn, we use "fink run" in command line to submit our job to yarn, one day we had an exception on flink job, as we didn't enable the flink restart strategy so it simply failed, but eventually we found that the job status was "SUCCEED" from the yarn application list, which we expect to be "FAILED".

Flink CLI log:

```
06/12/2018 03:13:37 FlatMap (getTagStorageMapper.flatMap)(23/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 GroupReduce (ResultReducer.reduceGroup)(31/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 FlatMap (SubClassEDFJoinMapper.flatMap)(29/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 CHAIN DataSource (SubClassInventory.AvroInputFormat.createInput) -> FlatMap (SubClassInventoryMapper.flatMap)(27/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 GroupReduce (OutputReducer.reduceGroup)(28/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 CHAIN DataSource (SubClassInventory.AvroInputFormat.createInput) -> FlatMap (BIMBQMInstrumentMapper.flatMap)(27/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 GroupReduce (BIMBQMGovCorpReduce.reduceGroup)(30/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 FlatMap (BIMBQMEVMJoinMapper.flatMap)(32/32) switched to CANCELED 
06/12/2018 03:13:37 Job execution switched to status FAILED.
No JobSubmissionResult returned, please make sure you called ExecutionEnvironment.execute()
2018-06-12 03:13:37,625 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient                       - Sending shutdown request to the Application Master
2018-06-12 03:13:37,625 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient                       - Start application client.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,630 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Notification about new leader address akka.tcp://flink@ip-10-97-46-149.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45663/user/jobmanager with session ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,632 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,633 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Received address of new leader akka.tcp://flink@ip-10-97-46-149.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45663/user/jobmanager with session ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,634 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Disconnect from JobManager null.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,635 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Trying to register at JobManager akka.tcp://flink@ip-10-97-46-149.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45663/user/jobmanager.
2018-06-12 03:13:37,688 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Successfully registered at the ResourceManager using JobManager Actor[akka.tcp://flink@ip-10-97-46-149.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45663/user/jobmanager#182802345]
2018-06-12 03:13:38,648 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Sending StopCluster request to JobManager.
2018-06-12 03:13:39,480 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient                       - Application application_1528772982594_0001 finished with state FINISHED and final state SUCCEEDED at 1528773218662
2018-06-12 03:13:39,480 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterClient                       - YARN Client is shutting down
2018-06-12 03:13:39,582 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Stopped Application client.
2018-06-12 03:13:39,583 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.ApplicationClient                       - Disconnect from JobManager Actor[akka.tcp://flink@ip-10-97-46-149.tr-fr-nonprod.aws-int.thomsonreuters.com:45663/user/jobmanager#182802345].
```

Flink job manager Log:

```
FlatMap (BIMBQMEVMJoinMapper.flatMap) (32/32) (67a002e07fe799c1624a471340c8cf9d) switched from CANCELING to CANCELED.
Try to restart or fail the job Flink Java Job at Tue Jun 12 03:13:17 UTC 2018 (1086cedb3617feeee8aace29a7fc6bd0) if no longer possible.
Requesting new TaskManager container with 8192 megabytes memory. Pending requests: 1
Job Flink Java Job at Tue Jun 12 03:13:17 UTC 2018 (1086cedb3617feeee8aace29a7fc6bd0) switched from state FAILING to FAILED.
Could not restart the job Flink Java Job at Tue Jun 12 03:13:17 UTC 2018 (1086cedb3617feeee8aace29a7fc6bd0) because the restart strategy prevented it.
Unregistered task manager ip-10-97-44-186/10.97.44.186. Number of registered task managers 31. Number of available slots 31
Stopping JobManager with final application status SUCCEEDED and diagnostics: Flink YARN Client requested shutdown
Shutting down cluster with status SUCCEEDED : Flink YARN Client requested shutdown
Unregistering application from the YARN Resource Manager
Waiting for application to be successfully unregistered.
```

Can anybody help me understand why does yarn say my flink job was "SUCCEED"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reported application status in Yarn does not reflect the status of the executed job but the status of the Flink cluster since this is the Yarn application. Thus, the final status of the Yarn application only depends on whether the Flink cluster finished properly or not. Differently said, if a job fails, then it does not necessarily mean that the Flink cluster failed. These are two different things.

Comment: Shouldn't be Flink ApplicationMaster set the job status to yarn? If that is the case, then why doesn't Flink AM set the failure status to yarn when it found flink job is failure?

Comment: Because a job failure does not mean that the Flink application has failed. There is a distinction between the Flink application/cluster and the Flink job being executed  by the cluster.

Comment: So I am writing a rest service that provide functionality to submit a flink job to yarn, and monitor that job, recover it when flink job failed. In that case how could I know whether flink job is failed or not, I am using a single job manager per job mode to submit flink job, so the job manager may have already been shutdown when job failed, so I have to rely on yarn application status, is there a solution for that?

Comment: To be precise one has to do a distinction between the job mode and the session mode. When using the job mode and running the job in detached mode, then the status should be reported correctly. This, however, only works in detached mode because in attached mode we have to start a session cluster underneath also if the user starts a job in job mode. The reason is that Flink jobs can consist of multiple parts (eager execution calls like `print` or `collect` in batch mode). Long story short, run your job in job mode and detached and things should hopefully work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, will try